# Can't get right width or outerWidth of <label> element

Tags: jquery, forms, label, width

simply can not understand this problem I have - I need the `.outerWidth()` of a `<label>` element, but it keeps returning a value that is different from the one I can read out of my firebug?

`.outerHeight` works just fine though.

**SOLVED**: *Note to self:* custom fonts and calculations of width does not work all that well, lol

Comment: Could you show us your HTML and JavaScript?  Checking for inner/outer width can be tricky since it varies by browsers, jQuery does a good job normalizing the quirks though.

Comment: @John Strickler: Thanks for help - found solution - read above :-)

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. Don't write "SOLVED" in the title. ;)

Comment: @Splynx What is the solution?

Comment: @bluish: well I kind of think my approach was ok though - I changed the title to SOLVED so people would not have to bother looking to help from frontpage - and I added the solution in the main post with capital letters SOLVED: and then the solution - will follow your guys styling though and post as reply

Comment: @Šime Vidas: The problem rather than the solution was that I was using custom fonts - the browser renders the <label> element first with its default font it seems.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this way creates confusion in StackOverflow. If you post the solution as an answer and accept it, your question will appear as solved, with no need to read the title. See "How do I ask questions here?" section at http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: @blush: 21 more hours till I can accept my own reply as the solution :-D

Answer (score 4):

When you use custom fonts, you must use the `.outerHeight` method on `$(window).load(function(){}`, not `$(document).ready(function(){}`. The first case waits for all the elements of the window to be loaded (including the custom font and the image) otherwise in the second case it is ready before the custom element is loaded and it not know the dimension of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Enclose inline code examples with backticks  to improve readability.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need `.outerWidth(true)` wich includes the margin of the element.

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/ for more specific information on the outerWidth function.

Comment: Found solution - custom fonts and widths dont match all that well lol

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION/PROBLEM: I used custom fonts - must be a workaround though - dont have time to find it yet :-D