# $.width() returns different results when using custom fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

Here is the situation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // this will return different result
  alert($('#foo').width());
  // than this !!!
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert($('#foo').width());
  }, 1000);
});
```

CSS (in `<head>` section):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Headland+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
... and
#foo {
    font-family: 'Headland One', serif;
}
```

When i use standard fonts (Arial for example) everything fine (`.width()` returning same result in both cases)

Is there any workaround different than `setTimeout` to get proper `.width()` value and keep custom fonts?

Comment: Can you show what `foo` is please (with regards to the way the element is defined), and if there are any events attached to it?

Comment: Found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539602/cant-get-right-width-or-outerwidth-of-label-element

Comment: @OfirBaruch indeed he had same problem as me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it loads a distant font. You should use `$(window).load()` rather than `$(document).ready()` : the first one will be triggered when all the distant fonts / stylesheets / scripts and images have been downloaded, the second one only when the DOM is ready.

Comment: `$(window).load()` did the job. Thank you

Comment: Wow, really? I've been looking for the answer to this for around a year. Can't believe it was so simple.